# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead (React)

Tags: reactjs, express, components, backend

I want to display this "What" in my React App but I still get the same error. It actually logs it in the console but on the page there's always the same error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead (React)
```

Express Route:

```
const express = require('express');
router = express.Router();

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("What")
});

module.exports = router;
```

React Component:

```
import React from 'react';

class Login extends React.Component {
    render() {
        function BackendRes() {
            const response = fetch("/login")
                                .then(res => res.text())
                                .then(text => console.log(text));
            return response;
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <BackendRes />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: Are you trying to show a text in frontend which is coming from express (`What` is the text express api sending as the response) ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `componentDidMount` life cycle method to invoke the api during the initial rendering only. Then set the `state` to keep the data coming from the api as follows. Then use the `state` to show the `text` inside a `div`.

```
import React from "react";

class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: "",
    };
    this.BackendRes = this.BackendRes.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.BackendRes();
  }

  BackendRes() {
    const response = fetch("/login")
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((text) => {
        this.setState({ data: text });
        console.log(text);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.data}</div>;
  }
}

export default Login;
```